# Subversion Repository Structure for MSBI

Tags: svn, reporting-services, ssas, data-modeling, tabular

We are just getting started with Microsoft's stack of tools as our BI solution.

We will be creating/using SSRS Reports, SSAS Tabular Models, Excel Services.PowerPivot models and PowerView reports for each functional area within our company.

For each functional area say ("Human Resources") we will be having a set of Reports, Data models, Dashboards etc

I was wondering if anyone of you could point me in the right direction for maintaining all the projects under Version control ( We will be using SVN ). Is there a standard way of maintaining all these diverse kinds of files/folders under SVN ?

Or in simple terms could you point me the benefits of using one over other in the following.

1) Create separate folders for each Functional Area  such as "Human Resources", "Sales" etc and house all the reports, models related to that functional area within their respective folders

The folder structure would look something like this

**Human Resources - > HR Models ->** HRDataModelProject1 ( This level will be the root for svn - And developers will checkout projects from this level )
**Human Resources - > HR Reports ->** ReportProject1

**Sales- > Sales Models ->** SalesModelProject1
**Sales- > Sales Reports ->** SalesReportProject1,

Or

2) Create separate folders for each content type such as Data Models, Reports etc as separate folders and house reports or models for each functional area

**Models - > HumanResources - >** HRDataModelProject1  ( This level will be the root for svn - And developers will checkout projects from this level )
**Models - > Sales - >** SalesModelProject1

**Reports - > HumanResources - >** HRReportProject1
**Reports - > Sales - >** Sales ReportProject1

Are there any pros and cons of the above methods? Or is there any other way to do it more efficiently ? Your advice is very much appreciated !

Many Thanks,

BiDev

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first version, as it keeps things that are related more closely together. If in future, you will have have a requirement to change an HR report, and that maybe needs an additional attribute in the cube, which again needs maybe a small change in the ETL process to be filled, then all these changes would be in one area, and not spread across different parts of the repository.

Having said that, your second version will also work, and it may be preferred by the administrative staff deploying the solution, as they will then know where to look for Integration Services packages, for SQL scripts, for reports, or for Analysis Services projects.